# Is there any benefit in reporting a model's regression and residual degree of freedom if I already report the no. of obs, F-value, RMSE, and R-sq?

Tags: regression, degrees-of-freedom, reporting

Is there any benefit in reporting a model's regression and residual degrees of freedom in the regression results table if I already report the following:

- Number of observation used in the model
- Model's F value and Prob (F) -- to test the overall significance of the regression model
- Model's Root MSE
- Model's R-square and adj. R-square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is the benefit to report number of covariates/independent variables. (I think model's regression degree of freedom = number of covaraites). DF of residual = # of observation - # of covariates - 1. So given you already reported # of the observation, you need to report one of # of covariates or DF of residual.

The benefit to report one more number is it makes reported F value meaningful. Otherwise, the reported F value is garbage, because F distribution has two DFs as parameters. DF for numerator is # of covariates and DF for denominator is # of observation - # of covariates -1.